# How can you web scrape with R when the URL does not change

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I need some help with scraping  multiple pages as all the URLs is similar to the first page. Kindly suggest a workaround.

Second issue, I am unable to select the address and description of each business using .mapItem. Instead of .mapItem i would like to extract the **data-comp-addr** field.

````
library(rvest)
webpage <- read_html("http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/search/all/legal")
webpage

```{r}
name_html <- webpage %>% html_nodes(".normal_title")
name <- html_text(name_html, trim = TRUE)
head(name)

desc_html <- webpage %>% html_nodes(".mapItem")
head(desc_html)
```
````

## Attempt to write to csv

```
library(readr)
df = data.frame(vectorName, vectorAddress, vectorDescription)
glimpse(df)

write_csv(df, "legal.csv")
```

Issue with above chunk, I have duplicates entries of vectorDescription those empty fields are repeats of the earlier entries

Comment: Could you add some other urls which you'd like to include?

Comment: @amrrs this is the URL http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/search/all/legal even if i am in page 2 it still show this URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you want to do scraping multiple pages?

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

#Login options
urlLog <- 'http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/user/login'
session <- html_session(urlLog)
form <- html_form(read_html(urlLog))[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(form, searchby = 'Your username here', keys = 'Your password here')

count = 0

for(numPage in 1:3){

        # Create and read the page address
        page = paste('http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/search/all/legal/?page', '=', numPage)
        nPage <- str_replace_all(page, pattern=" ", repl="")
        url <- jump_to(session, nPage)

        # Read the 20 items of each the page
        for(numItem in 1:20){

                print(paste(' -- Reading the item', numItem, ' on page', numPage))

                item =  paste('item', numItem, sep = "", collapse = NULL)
                xPath <- paste('//*[@id=',item, ']', sep = "'", collapse = NULL)

                # read the path
                readPath <- nPage %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = xPath)

                # Get values
                name  <- readPath %>% html_nodes(".normal_title") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
                lengthName <- length(name)

                address <- readPath %>% html_nodes(".mapItem") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
                lengthAddress <- length(address)

                bDescription <- readPath %>% html_nodes(".com_business_card") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
                lengthDesc <- length(bDescription)

                if(lengthName == 0){

                        name = 'NA'

                }

                if(lengthDesc == 0){

                        lengthAddress = 'NA'

                }

                if(lengthDesc == 0){

                        bDescription = 'NA'

                }

                # Store variables
                if(count == 0){

                        vectorName <- name
                        vectorAddress <- address
                        vectorDescription <- bDescription
                }else{

                        vectorName <- c(vectorName, name)
                        vectorAddress <- c(vectorAddress, address)
                        vectorDescription <- c(vectorDescription, bDescription)

                }


                count = count + 1

        }


}


df <- data.frame(vectorName, vectorAddress, vectorDescription)
```

Comment: Yes, however I am not able to get the element I want as stated from the website such as the address and business description

Comment: I added another lines to get name, address and description. I hope this work.

Comment: Thanks Luis it seem like it is a partial solution, I am able to retrieve those parameters but the output run on the same page it does not go to the next page any idea why?

Comment: It seems to be something similar to this post however can you suggest a R approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974952/scraping-data-from-two-different-pages-having-same-url

Comment: You should create a list of links like this one _pages <-
 c("http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/search/all/legal/?page=1", "http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/search/all/legal/?page=2", "http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/search/all/legal/?page=3")_ the last one is 70

Comment: I found out I can the link for the next pages how can i make it dynamic for the for loop to reach till the last page?
 http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/search/all/Legal?page=2

Comment: Luis the last part where you store the result is it possible to manipulate it into a data frame to export out as a csv file?

Comment: I attempted this codes 'library(readr)
df = data.frame(vectorName, vectorAddress, vectorDescription)
glimpse(df)

write_csv(df, "legal.csv")' however, the vectorDescription which overrides the rest of the column even if it is empty with duplicates

Comment: Ok, I noticed that some card does not have any description. I will search how solve this

Comment: Hi Luis, i am not sure why from page 2 onwards it reads character(0)
character(0)
character(0)

Comment: it does not seem to work can you clarify on the above errors

Comment: I have further errors :Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 307.

Comment: I can be because the page ask you to login after many requests. One option to solve this is to login. I updated the code to do that. Other option is to make the consultation in parts.

Comment: Hi Luis, it happens to be fine when I am on different network, however one error i facing is for all the vectors from page 2 onwards returns character(0)

Comment: You are correct, I don't know why suddenly the items in each page are from item1 to item20. I change this on the code, you could remplace the code from the line `for(numItem in 1:20){ `